# What is a Dominant Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

*In the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463).*

If a word conforms to a specific pattern, I call it a Dominant Word™. Use the words below to figure out the pattern!

(Pardon the formatting, I haven't figured out how to use the popular template)

| Dominant Words™ | Not Dominant Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| MEOW | BARK |
| COMMUNE | GATHER |
| VOID | ABYSS |
| COUNTRY | JAZZ |
| MELT | FREEZE |
| TEXTILE | PANTS |
| KING | QUEEN |
| NOODLE | WONTON |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Dominant Words™,Not Dominant Words™
MEOW,BARK
COMMUNE,GATHER
VOID,ABYSS
COUNTRY,JAZZ
MELT,FREEZE
TEXTILE,PANTS
KING,QUEEN
NOODLE,WONTON
```

Explain the pattern and the question title as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Dominant Word:

> Contains at least one letter which is also a Roman numeral (I, V, X, L, C, D, M).

Like so:

> **M**EOW, **C**O**MM**UNE, **V**O**ID**, **C**OUNTRY, **M**E**L**T, TE**X**T**IL**E, K**I**NG, NOO**DL**E

As for the name:

> This may potentially reference the *dominance* of the Roman Empire, historically speaking. Furthermore, **D**O**MI**NANT follows the rule itself...

Comment: you're prompt and accurate!

Comment: @Luke Well, if I'd missed this one I'd have been **LIVID** ;-)